# Move Data from one Node to another in Firebase Realtime Database in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a project where user request for our valet services and on the other end valet accepts request.

I am using using Firebase as backend and on request customer uid is save on 'request' child.

When valet accepts request, customer uid should move from 'request' node to 'on progress' node.

How can i do that?

Comment: Read the source data, write it to the destination, then delete the original.  There is no move operation that does it all at the same time.

Comment: @DougStevenson, Thank you so much. You saved my time I was busy reading various documents to get what I want.